# Changing the regular price according to the user's group

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to change the regular price of a product according to the user's group. I will have Wholesaler A, Wholesaler B, and Wholesaler  C as my group.

So each time a customer logs in and checks out the products he will see a different set of price than the other users who belong to another group. Please check if my approach is correct?

```
function change_product_price( $price ) {

if ( class_exists( 'Groups_Group' ) && class_exists( 'Groups_User' ) ) {
    if ( $user_id = get_current_user_id() ) {
        $user = new Groups_User( $user_id );

        if ( $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'A' ) ) {
            if ( $user->is_member( $group->group_id ) ) {
                $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_a_price_field', true );
            }
        } else if ( $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'B' ) ) {
            if ( $user->is_member( $group->group_id ) ) {
                $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_b_price_field', true );
            }
        } else if ( $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'C' ) ) {
            if ( $user->is_member( $group->group_id ) ) {
                $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_c_price_field', true );
            }
        }
    }
}

return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_product_price', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better idea than this one. I should rather check the User's Role.